# Drawing image with BufferedImage causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, graphics, nullpointerexception, awt, paint

I'm trying to draw an image to a simple canvas in Java. When I run the program, the image draws correctly, but the program throws a NullPointerException (at the line where drawImage is called) immediately after. I'm using an update() method that automatically repaints the scene:

```
public void update(Graphics brush) {
    paint(buffer.getGraphics());
    brush.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    if (on) {
        sleep(50);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

My paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    brush.drawImage(mainChar.sprite, 0, 0, null);
}//paint
```

mainChar.sprite is a BufferedImage object. As far as I can tell, mainChar and mainChar.sprite are initialized properly when the program begins. The strange part is, again, that the image draws correctly, but the program crashes soon after.

EDIT: The exception is thrown, but the program doesn't actually crash. With that in mind, I can carry on with this error persisting, but I'd still like to know what's causing it.

Oh, and here's the console dump:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Draegix.paint(Draegix.java:44)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:347)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4937)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Draegix.paint(Draegix.java:44)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:347)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4937)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Why AWT and not Swing? You should almost never call paint directly you know. Don't assume that anything is initialized until you test it. Test any variable on the line throwing the NPE before that line to see if it is null. Then you will *know* what has been initialized. `Thread.sleep(...)` in the GUI thread is a no-no as well.

Comment: I'll be honest: I'm very new to Java graphics and I'm basically using what I have. What issues could Thread.sleep cause, and what would be preferable to simulate a framerate?

So as it turns out, the program hasn't actually crashed at the point it throws the exception-- I think I'll add that to the question text.

Comment: Ehh no offense but that's some ugly code. I'd suggest reading tutorials on active painting and threading.

Comment: Without a runnabled example, it's impossible to guess why, I would suggest putting in `System.out`'s to determine the state of the various objects